# How to edit word document in Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created an android Xamarin app. This will download files from the server and store them to the internal storage(MyDocument) of the android device. I want to open this file and want to edit it via a supported 3rd party application for editing.

I am using the below code to open in installed application.
await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest("", new FileResult(filePath)));

It always opens in read-only mode. I can not overwrite the content of the file. If I edit its content it never saves, and always asks to create a new copy.

How can I edit and overwrite the file?

Comment: The third party app does not have permissions to write to files in your apps folder

Comment: Thank you Jason. What is the best way to achieve so? How can I edit the document ?

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/create-word-document-in-xamarin

Comment: The file in the public storage such as in the Document/Download folder can only be write by the app which creates the file and the system file manager.

Comment: Thank you Liyun. Is there any other place where I can store the file and edit by 3rd party app like ms word ?

Comment: You can only edit the original file by 3rd party app in the system file manager.

Comment: Thank you Liyun. But this works well in iOS. I am able to edit the document in ios. So just confused why not in android.

Comment: This is because the ios and the android have different file permission.